# Pass text from a TextFormField to another class in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have 2 pages and what I want to achieve is that on Page1 when someone enters text and hits 'Send Message' I want the text from the TextFormField to display in page2. Is there a way to do this?

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  final _chatController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _getFooter(), 
      body: Page2());
  }

  Widget _getFooter() {
    return Container(
        child: Row(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _chatController,
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Text("Send Message"),
      )
    ]));
  }
}



class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("{Display text from page 1 here"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is about how to transfer text from TextFormfield to Page 2 when you click on Send message button so according to me my answer is perfect based on your requirement please check once https://stackoverflow.com/a/61290762/12386821

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  final _chatController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: _getFooter(),
        body: Page2(text: _chatController.text));
  }

  Widget _getFooter() {
    return Container(
        child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _chatController,
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {

              });
            },
            child: Text("Send Message"),
          )
        ]));
  }
}



class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  Page2({this.text});
  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.text),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full code

```
class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
      final _chatController = TextEditingController();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: _getFooter(), 
          body: Container());
      }

      Widget _getFooter() {
        return Container(
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _chatController,
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
             Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Page2(message : _chatController.text ),
          ),
        );
},
            child: Text("Send Message"),
          )
        ]));
      }
    }



    class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
      String message;
      Page2({Key key, @required this.message} : super(key key);
      @override
      _Page2State createState() => _Page2State(message : message);
    }

    class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
      String message;
      _Page2State({Key key, @required this.message} : super(key : key);
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Text(message),
        );
      }
    }
```